# No way to use in cypher the term case insensitivity = ~ (? i), when I'm using parameter?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I tried this way but it did not work.

```
params.put("name", g );   
final QueryResult<Map<String,Object>> result = engine.query("MATCH a:Conceito --> b:Livro WHERE a.nome =~'(?i){name}' return b.autor, b.titulo, b.edicao", params); //executa query
```

This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestResultException: expected valid query body
"MATCH a:Conceito --> b:Livro WHERE a.nome =~'(?i){name}' return b.autor, b.titulo, b.edicao"
                                                 ^ at
```

The query runs only if remove the expression `~ (?i)`

Excuse my English because I'm from Brazil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me, see: http://console.neo4j.org/r/tutchx

```
start n=node:node_auto_index(name='Neo') 
where n.name =~ '(?i)neo' 
return n
```

As you use a parameter, you have to pass in the whole regexp (including the flag) as param value:

```
params.put("name", "(?i)"+g );   
final QueryResult<Map<String,Object>> result = 
  engine.query("MATCH a:Conceito --> b:Livro WHERE a.nome =~ {name} return b.autor, b.titulo, b.edicao", params); //executa query
```